# How to set the height of the columns in Bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, bootstrap-4

How can I set the height for the columns to be the same like having a match between each of them
This is the html code for the 3 columns.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 list-group">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">asd</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">asd</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">asd</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 list-group">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">asd</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">asd</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 list-group">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">asd</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

And I want to achieve something like this :
[image]

Comment: plz check the link :  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/sizing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `h-auto` to `col` class and it's child give `h-100` makes **same height**

And add  `align-items:center !important;display:grid !important;` to `list-group-item` class.

```css
.list-group-item{
  align-items:center !important;
  display:grid !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 list-group h-auto text-center">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item h-100">asd</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item h-100">asd</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item h-100">asd</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 list-group h-auto text-center">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item h-100">asd</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item h-100">asd</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 list-group h-auto text-center">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item h-100">asd</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please try this

Comment: You don't need to keep adding comments to all your answers to tag the OPs - they have asked the question so they will obviously check back for an answer when they are ready, and they will see your answer along with any others then.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/U0SLEhM.png Works good but the last one is not centered :/

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dITu6.png this work properly in snippet